# How do I output file paths relative to a non-git directory with git diff?

Tags: git

> parentdirectory
>
> > childdirectory (this is the git repo)
> >
> > > changedfile

Using git diff, is it possible to output changes to files relative to a different directory?  If I run git diff --name-status on childdirectory, it will output:

M changedfile

I need it to output:

M childdirectory/changedfile

I am using a Git hook and piping the changes to a program that is reliant on the file path relative to the parentdirectory.  I can't hardcode the parent directory to the file path because the modified files may be deeper than 1 directory down.

Edit: To clarify why I don't want to hardcode - I plan on reusing this hook for many, many repos that will all have their own paths from the parentdirectory.  It may be the only solution though (I'm hoping not) and I'll just have to make it some kind of configuration.

Edit: I updated the output and clarified that I need it to run with the `git diff --name-status` flag.

Comment: Are `--src-prefix` and `--dst-prefix` insufficient?

Comment: I have updated my question to show that I need it to work with the `--name-status` flag.  `--src-prefix` and `--dst-prefix` doesn't seem to have any effect with the `--name-status` flag on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're piping the output of `git diff --name-status`, why not simply add a `sed` to your pipeline to tweak the paths?

```
$ git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD
M       Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt
$ git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD | sed $'s,[ACDMRTUX]\t,&dir/,'
M   dir/Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt
```

(The `$'...'` form allows using `\t` to encode a tab.  Usually in a script I set a variable—`TAB=$'\t'`—then use double quotes and `${TAB}` as needed to insert the tab.  Usually in scripts I need other variables expanded too, so this lets me use them in a consistent and clear way, rather than switching forms a bunch:

```
cmd "arg $VAR"$'\t'"$ANOTHER"$'\r\n'"$MORE etc"
```

In any case, the point here is that `--name-status` has a nice known output form with an embedded tab, so we can key off that.)